Update drawing onto the canvas to have horizontal padding
I have this logic to draw digital time on a canvas. it is working fine, but the text is cutting on the edge. How can I update this for the text to sit in the middle and has a padding horizontally, which will react to any screen size.
private fun drawDigitalClock(canvas: Canvas,context: Context) {
    paint = Paint()
    val formatService = FormatService.getInstance(context)
    val timeText = formatService.formatTime(time)
    paint.textSize = fontSize.toFloat() * 4.5f
    paint.color = Color.WHITE
    paint.textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
    canvas.drawText(timeText, width / 2f, height / 2f, paint)
}



Try setting  paint.textSize = canvas.width - padding * 2f.

Thank you but this is not working

Oh, it should be:
val textWidth = paint.measureText(timeText)
val adjustedTextSize = paint.textSize * (width - totalPadding)/ textWidth
paint.textSize = adjustedTextSize 

The issue is with the font size, try to update paint.textSize = fontSize.toFloat() * 3.5f.
Increasing the size will make the text to be much bigger
private fun drawDigitalClock(canvas: Canvas,context: Context) {
  paint = Paint()
  val formatService = FormatService.getInstance(context)
  val timeText = formatService.formatTime(time)
  paint.textSize = fontSize.toFloat() * 4.5f
  paint.color = Color.WHITE
  paint.textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
  canvas.drawText(timeText, width / 2f, height / 2f, paint)
}


thanks...  I see the issue is with the  fontSize.toFloat(), adjusting fixed the issue

private fun drawDigitalClock(canvas: Canvas,context: Context) {
    paint = Paint()
    val formatService = FormatService.getInstance(context)
    val timeText = formatService.formatTime(time)
    paint.textSize = fontSize.toFloat() * 4.5f//nominal- just for measuring purposes (i.e.actual value doesn't matter)
    paint.color = Color.WHITE
    paint.textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
    
    //Dynamically adjust width of any text to fit in the available width
    val textWidth = paint.measureText(timeText) 
    val adjustedTextSize = paint.textSize * (width - totalHorizontalPadding)/ textWidth 
    paint.textSize = adjustedTextSize 
    
    canvas.drawText(timeText, width / 2f, height / 2f, paint)
}



Thanks.. reducing the font size fixed the issue

@Yakubu You don't have to fixed the size. The code I provided will dynamically resize any text to fit in the provided (available) width. Different characters can have different widths

what will be the value of width and  totalPadding

setting the width to 3.5 fit all on all screen.. this approach is not clear
(width - totalPadding)/ textWidth

@Yakubu, you have to set it to your intended horizontal padding (total of both sides). You haven't specified it in your question but you mentioned it.

actually that is not a padding from the class, I have updated the code now, before I was having an image view for background

I have updated the code now and I am fine.. thank you
